# Rules that govern Checking for ExpectedException thrown in JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, exception, junit4

My task was to count the number of mismatches(different characters) in the given two Strings. Although; there was **two conditions** that needs to be fulfilled.

> If the lengths of given two Strings are not same; **throw an Exception with appropriate message.**
>
> If only one input String is provided; **throw an Exception with appropriate message.**

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
class Hamming {
    private final String leftString;
    private final String rightString;

    public Hamming(String leftString, String rightString) {
        this.leftString = leftString;
        this.rightString = rightString;
    }

    public int getHammingDistance() {
        int hammingDistance = 0;
        int secondCharIndex = 0;
        if (leftString.length() == 0 && rightString.length() != 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("left string must not be empty.");
        if (rightString.length() == 0 && leftString.length() != 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("right string must not be empty.");
        if (leftString.length() != rightString.length())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("left and right string must be of equal length.");
        for (char ch : leftString.toCharArray()) {
            if (ch != rightString.charAt(secondCharIndex)) hammingDistance++;
            secondCharIndex++;
        }
        return hammingDistance;
    }
}
```

Now, when I am running this solution directly; it is working as expected. You can find the run sample of the above code [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/Sy3n-hyj8)

When I'm trying to run the same code with **Junit Test Coverage**; the same code fails all the test cases which involved Exceptions. Below is my `HammingTest.java`

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThrows;

import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;

public class HammingTest {

    @Test
    public void testNoDistanceBetweenEmptyStrings() {
        assertEquals(0, new Hamming("", "").getHammingDistance());
    }

//    @Ignore("Remove to run test")
    @Test
    public void testNoDistanceBetweenShortIdenticalStrings() {
        assertEquals(0, new Hamming("A", "A").getHammingDistance());
    }

//    @Ignore("Remove to run test")
    @Test
    public void testCompleteDistanceInSingleLetterDifferentStrings() {
        assertEquals(1, new Hamming("G", "T").getHammingDistance());
    }

//    @Ignore("Remove to run test")
    @Test
    public void testDistanceInLongIdenticalStrings() {
        assertEquals(0, new Hamming("GGACTGAAATCTG", "GGACTGAAATCTG").getHammingDistance());
    }

//    @Ignore("Remove to run test")
    @Test
    public void testDistanceInLongDifferentStrings() {
        assertEquals(9, new Hamming("GGACGGATTCTG", "AGGACGGATTCT").getHammingDistance());
    }

//    @Ignore("Remove to run test")
    @Test
    public void testValidatesFirstStringNotLonger() {
        IllegalArgumentException expected =
            assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> new Hamming("AATG", "AAA"));

        assertThat(expected)
            .hasMessage("left and right string must be of equal length.");
    }

//    @Ignore("Remove to run test")
    @Test
    public void testValidatesSecondStringNotLonger() {
        IllegalArgumentException expected =
            assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> new Hamming("ATA", "AGTG"));

        assertThat(expected)
            .hasMessage("left and right string must be of equal length.");
    }

//    @Ignore("Remove to run test")
    @Test
    public void testDisallowLeftEmptyString() {
        IllegalArgumentException expected =
            assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> new Hamming("", "G"));

        assertThat(expected)
            .hasMessage("left string must not be empty.");
    }

//    @Ignore("Remove to run test")
    @Test
    public void testDisallowRightEmptyString() {
        IllegalArgumentException expected =
            assertThrows(
                IllegalArgumentException.class,
                () -> new Hamming("G", ""));

        assertThat(expected)
            .hasMessage("right string must not be empty.");
    }

}
```

I am using the project as **gradle project.** So the report which generated shown the below problem:

[image]

**What solved my problem:**

After working for long; when I finally tried to **put the exception throwing conditions inside the Constructor**; it solved my problem. Every test case was passed. Some thing like:

```
public Hamming(String leftString, String rightString) {
        if (leftString.length() == 0 && rightString.length() != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("left string must not be empty.");
        } else if (rightString.length() == 0 && leftString.length() != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("right string must not be empty.");
        } else if (leftString.length() != rightString.length()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("leftString and rightString must be of equal length.");
        }
        this.leftSting = leftString;
        this.rightString = rightString;
    }
```

**What is my doubt:**

1. Why the solution of putting the exception throwing conditions inside the constructor worked?
2. When I was trying to put the exception throwing conditions inside the `getHamming()` method; why the tests were failing?
3. When I'm running the same `Hamming` class as mentioned earlier without JUnit; it is working as expected. Why is this happeneing?

Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: In your failing test(s), you don't call the method which throws the exception, you only invoke the constructor.

Comment: As an aside, there isn't any need to create an instance of the Hamming class: just declare the method as static, and give it the two strings as parameters.

Comment: @AndyTurner; thank you for the same. It is very painful how I missed it. Just one doubt I have; is it the best practice to put the Exception conditions inside constructor or we could do something else **if we are not allowed to edit the TestHamming.java class.**

Comment: it is best practice to fail as soon as possible, in order that the failure is as close as possible to the thing which caused it (passing empty/unequal strings). In particular, not putting the exception in the constructor here leaves you with a totally crippled instance of `Hamming` that will always throw an exception. If you throw the exception in the constructor instead, you never get this invalid instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to call `getHammingDistance()`, that's why your test cases were failing. Let's take a test case and see why.

```java
@Test
public void testValidatesFirstStringNotLonger() {
    IllegalArgumentException expected =
        assertThrows(
            IllegalArgumentException.class,
            () -> new Hamming("AATG", "AAA"));

    assertThat(expected)
        .hasMessage("left and right string must be of equal length.");
}
```

The first `assertThrows` checks whether `new Hamming("AATG", "AAA")` fails with an `IllegalArgumentException`. Since the exception was raised in method `getHammingDistance()` instead, the assertion fails.

This would have worked:

```
@Test
public void testValidatesFirstStringNotLonger() {
    Hamming hamming = new Hamming("AATG", "AAA");

    IllegalArgumentException expected =
        assertThrows(
            IllegalArgumentException.class,
            () -> hamming.getHammingDistance());

    assertThat(expected)
        .hasMessage("left and right string must be of equal length.");
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you have to be very careful with `assertThrows` and runtime exceptions, in particular common ones like IAE. The IAE could be thrown by either the constructor or the method invocation, and you might not be catching the one you expect. It is best to only do one thing in the lambda which throws the expected exception type (that is, construct the instance outside, then use it in the lambda); however, the problem is mitigated by checking the exception message.

Comment: Thanks Andy! I edited the answer to make that more obvious where the exception is being expected to be raised.